# git commit and got error " [1] 3910 segmentation fault (core dumped) "

Tags: git, git-commit

I use git commit and got an error: 
[1]    3910 segmentation fault (core dumped)

This is my ~/.gitconfig file:

```
[include]
    path = ~/some/where/gitconfig
```

And I put my configuration in ~/some/where/gitconfig.

Any ideas?

Comment: So you had the file include itself?  Which of course would include itself, which would include itself, which ...  (It might be good for Git not to *crash* in this situation, but it's not going to work.)  Or am I misinterpreting this, does ~/.gitconfig only include the other file and not vice versa?

Comment: What's in `~/some/where/gitconfig` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the reason.
You can not put something like:

```
[action]
    subaction
```

You must give a value to the subaction.

but you can put something like:

```
[action]
```

So, You can use one gitconfiguration file to call other configuration files.